# Calling more than one function in PHP

Tags: php, function

I have a page where I'm housing all of my functions that make calls to the database. In my display page I'm trying to make calls to two separate functions. Is this not possible to do? Below is my code.

```
<?php
include 'includes/getData.php';
$memberBios = getActiveMemberBios();
$internBios = getActiveInternBios();
?>

<h3>Members</h3>
            <?php
                while($member = mysql_fetch_array($memberBios))
                {
                    $bioPic = $member['bioPic'];
                    $bioText = $member['bioText'];
                    $firstname = $member['firstname'];
                    $maidenname = $member['maidenname'];
                    $memberRole = $member['memberRole'];
                    $lastname = $member['lastname'];

                    echo
                    "<div class='row row__off-1 col-lg-12 wow fadeInUp' data-wow-delay='0.2s'>
                        <div class='col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12'>
                            <div class='text-center'>
                                <img src='".$bioPic."' alt='Biography Picture of Zion Dance Company Member '".$firstname.' '.$lastname." title='Biography Picture of Zion Dance Company Member '".$firstname.' '.$lastname. "height='305' width='270'/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12 text-center-xs'>
                            <h5 class='font-secondary-3'>
                                <a href='#'>".$firstname.' '.$maidenname.' '.$lastname."</a>
                            </h5>
                            <p class='color-primary off'>".$memberRole."</p>

                            <p>".$bioText."</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>";
                }
            ?>
            <h3>Interns</h3>
            <?php
                while($intern = mysql_fetch_array($internBios))
                {
                    $bioPic = $intern['bioPic'];
                    $bioText = $intern['bioText'];
                    $firstname = $intern['firstname'];
                    $maidenname = $intern['maidenname'];
                    $memberRole = $intern['memberRole'];
                    $lastname = $intern['lastname'];

                    echo
                    "<div class='row row__off-1 col-lg-12 wow fadeInUp' data-wow-delay='0.2s'>
                        <div class='col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12'>
                            <div class='text-center'>
                                <img src='".$bioPic."' alt='Biography Picture of Zion Dance Company Member '".$firstname.' '.$lastname." title='Biography Picture of Zion Dance Company Member '".$firstname.' '.$lastname. "height='305' width='270'/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12 text-center-xs'>
                            <h5 class='font-secondary-3'>
                                <a href='#'>".$firstname.' '.$maidenname.' '.$lastname."</a>
                            </h5>
                            <p class='color-primary off'>".$memberRole."</p>

                            <p>".$bioText."</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>";
                }
            ?>
```

Each method is calling a different stored procedure.

Each methods returns the data properly until they are called one right after the other.

```
function getActiveMemberBios()
{
    mysql_connect(ZDANCE_CONNECTION, ZDANCE_USER, ZDANCE_PASS);
    if(mysql_ping())
    {
        mysql_select_db(ZDANCE_HOST);
        $result = mysql_query("CALL usp_GetMemberBios(1)") or die("Query fail: " . mysql_error());

        return $result;

        mysql_close();
    }
}

function getActiveInternBios()
{
    mysql_connect(ZDANCE_CONNECTION, ZDANCE_USER, ZDANCE_PASS);
    if(mysql_ping())
    {
        mysql_select_db(ZDANCE_HOST);
        $result = mysql_query("CALL usp_GetInternBios(1)") or die("Query fail: " . mysql_error());

        return $result;

        mysql_close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can call as many separate functions as you wish.

Comment: Why would you think it's not possible?

Comment: For some reason when I try that the second call when I loop through won't give me anything but if I comment out the first one then it works.

Comment: And give us a content of the includes/getData.php file if you can.

Comment: See edits to question for "better" example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your functions didn't close theirs sql connections because `mysql_close` functions are placed after return operation. Try to replace this part of your functions code

```
return $result;

mysql_close();
```

with this

```
mysql_close();

return $result;
```

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful to future readers. What caused the problem and how does your code solve it?

Comment: Thanks @showdev for drawing attention to the lack of clarification in my answer. I did an edition already.